# How to navigate beetwen components with child router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I define main `router-outlet` to navigate between 2 components: `HomeComponent` and `ContactComponent`. But in `HomeComponent` I want to put second `router-outlet` (exactly at his child) to navigate between `EventListComponent` and `UserEventListComponent`.

I made something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: RightMenuComponent, outlet:'child', children: [
      { path: '', component: EventListComponent },
      { path: 'mylist', component: UserEventListComponent }
    ]}]
  },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: '**', component: Page404Component }
];
```

But it didnt work. If I remove `outlet:'child'` it duplicate me `EventListComponent` or `UserEventListComponent` depends on URL.

Any ideas how to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change that for:

```
[
{
  "path": "",
  "component": "HomeComponent",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "eventList",
      "component": "EventListComponent"
    },
    {
      "path": "mylist",
      "component": "UserEventListComponent"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "path": "contact",
  "component": "ContactComponent"
},
{
  "path": " **",
  "component": "Page404Component"
}
```

]

And the RightMenuComponent should be a component inside the HomeComponent, I mean, not a route child, just a HomeComponent's child.

I hope can help

Comment: You miss `RightMenuComponent`, But any way I tried that way but nothing change. It duplicates my `EventListComponent` or `UserEventListComponent`

Answer (score 0):

As the way you have it set up, you need three router outlets.

1. 1st, on app level for Home, Contact, 404 to be injected into the
   app.
2. 2nd, inside Home for RightMenu to be injected inside Home.
3. 3rd, inside RightMenu for Event and UserEvent to be injected inside Right
   Menu.

From the looks of it, you might find it redundant to keep injecting the one and only child for instance, to the Home Compoenent, instead of having them combined.

Comment: For what that 2nd router outlet? I tried to named every component with diffrent string path (without empty string) but it gives nothing diffrent. As before it duplicate my Components. 

HomeComponent have 3 child components but only RightComponents have children so it is necessary.

Comment: @Adriano Once again, your HomeComponent has children, then one of it's children - RightMenu - has children. Just for these two, you need two router-outlets. And then you also need anoter router outlet at app level. In other words, if you don't have router outlets three levels, then your setup won't work.

Comment: so you think I have to create separate module for 3 routers ?

Comment: @Adriano Module? No, unless you want to use lazy loading. Just putting in router outlets into correct templates should solve your issue.